# How does one build an spa with webpack when deploying Docker container to Heroku

Tags: django, docker, heroku, aurelia

I'm developing an Aurelia Single Page App that will talk to a REST api built with Django Rest Framework.

Without containers, I would have two buildpacks, one for Node that runs a script in the package.json file and another for Python that builds the Django app.

If I push a container image, then what mechanism replaces the node buildpack that calls the script in package.json to trigger webpack to create the asset bundles?

Answer (score 1):

> what mechanism replaces the node buildpack that calls the script in package.json

You're not really giving any info regarding your current setup and what you've tried already, so I'll assume you already know how to run docker on heroku, and that you got your current setup to work on heroku without docker.

If you've got a script called `build` in your package.json that kicks off the webpack build, and `start` that starts a node.js express app to serve your app from the webpack output folder, you'd do something like this in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.9.4

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

CMD npm run start
```

Of course this doesn't account for any copying and permission setting you may need to do, but that depends on your project setup.

The important bit is that you're essentially running the thing as a node app, and you need the appropriate scripts in your package.json to which you can delegate the building and running, so you only need to call one or two of those scripts from your Dockerfile. You don't want to be doing too much npm stuff there directly.